# NiFi PutSNS Processor Without Attaching Files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-nifi, amazon-sns

Pretty new to NiFi so apologies ahead of time if I'm entirely missing something here.

**Architecture:** I'm picking up some files from an ftp server, uploading to S3, and archiving back on to the server. If uploading to S3 fails, publish to an SNS topic.

[NiFi architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1DFJ.png)

**Goal:** In the event of a failure, NiFi will publish to an SNS topic to send out an email to support folks.

**Issue:** It looks like the file is being included in the payload that's sent off to SNS resulting in a file size error.

**What I've Tried**: I've tried removing flowfile attributes with the UpdateAttribute processor to remove the filename, using a LogMessage processor followed by the PutSNS processor, in addition to what's depicted in the diagram.

Is there a way to publish just a short message to SNS?

Here's an image of the error to make sure I'm not leaving anything out:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgoDu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PutSNS processor Sends the content of a FlowFile as a notification to the Amazon Simple Notification Service

So, you have to change content of flow file with ReplaceText or other processor before sending SNS.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll give this a try!

Comment: Yup that did it, thanks! I think where I went wrong was assuming that the PutSNS had some sort of template for publishing to SNS vs sending the content of the flowfile.

Comment: `ModifyBytes` which have the option to delete the flowfiles.